# The series $ Σ=(-1)^n 2^n z^n $ from n=0 to infinity wtih |z| <1/2 where it converges?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Where does this  series converges $ Σ=(-1)^n 2^n z^n $ with |z|<1/2

I am having problem to find solution on this one. How would you aproach it ?

EDIT: i dont know how to solve when i know that |z|<1/2. Isn't it diferent answer for if z>1  or if z<1 ?
I know that $ Σ=(-1)^n 2^n  $ diverges but what changes with Z ?

Comment: It's a *geometric series*.

Comment: Could you answer for $\sum(-1)^nz^n$ ?

Comment: If you didn't recognize this as  a geometric series you could still have applied ratio test or root test to answer it. Did you really make any attempt at all?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes. I know it diverges for that...But i dont know what i can do with Z...

Comment: Diverges "for that" ? What ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the problem with $\;z\;$ ...? In the first comment they tell you it is a geometric series with ratio $\;-2z\;$, and thus it converges iff

$$|-2z|<1\iff |z|<\frac12\;,\;\;\text{and its sum is}\;\;\;\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n2^nz^n=\frac1{1+2z}$$